# copy some index of one array to another array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this array,

```
SnegatvSph  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-0.25",@"-0.50",@"-0.75",@"-1.00",@"-1.25",@"-1.50",@"-1.75",@"-2.00",@"-2.25",@"-2.50",@"-2.75",@"-3.00",@"-3.25",@"-3.50",@"-3.75",@"-4.00",@"-4.25",@"-4.50",@"-4.75",@"-5.00",@"-5.25",@"-5.50",@"-5.75",@"-6.00",@"-6.25",@"-6.50",@"-6.75",@"-7.00",@"-7.25",@"-7.50",@"-7.75",@"-8.00",@"-8.25",@"-8.50",@"-8.75",@"-9.00",@"-9.25",@"-9.50",@"-9.75",@"-10.00",@"-10.25",@"-10.50",@"-10.75",@"-11.00",@"-11.25",     @"-11.50",@"-11.75",@"-12.00", nil];
```

from this array i want to add values from -4.25 to -8.50 to another array like

```
SpositvSph  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-4.25",@"-4.50",@"-4.75",@"-5.00",@"-5.25",@"-5.50",@"-5.75",@"-6.00",@"-6.25",@"-6.50",@"-6.75",@"-7.00",@"-7.25",@"-7.50",@"-7.75",@"-8.00",@"-8.25",@"-8.50", nil];
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use NSMutableArray to insertObjectAtIndex

Comment: NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:SpositvSph]; [arr insertObject:@"someValue" atIndex:YOURINDEX];

Comment: NSArray is static and NSMutableArray is dynamic means NSArray is only init time add but NSMutableArray is any time add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subarrayWithRange:` with `NSArray` like this.

```
NSInteger startIndex = [SnegatvSph indexOfObject:@"-4.25"];
NSInteger toIndex = [SnegatvSph indexOfObject:@"-8.50"];
if (startIndex < SnegatvSph.count && toIndex < SnegatvSph.count) {
    NSArray *newArray = [SnegatvSph subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, (toIndex - startIndex + 1))];
    NSLog(@"%@",newArray);
}
```